# Fastlane & Flutter - Google Api Error: Invalid request - Access Not Configured. Google Play

Tags: android, flutter, fastlane

What causes this error when using Fastlane and Flutter after running this :

`bundle exec fastlane beta`

> Google Api Error: Invalid request - Access Not Configured. Google Play
>   Developer API has not been used in project before or it is disabled.
>   Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/androidpublisher.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxx
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

When the Service Account is enabled and linked to the Play Store account with Release Manager, 
I read different conversations on github, but I couldnt get clear answers, I tried to increase the version of my APK since I uploaded one, but no luck.

This is my code in the `Fastfile` :

```
update_fastlane

default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  desc "Runs all the tests"
  lane :test do
    gradle(task: "test")
  end

  desc "Deploy an beta new version to the Google Play"
  lane :beta do
       gradle(
           task: 'assemble',
           build_type: 'Release'
         )
     upload_to_play_store(track: 'beta',
     version_code: 5,
     aab: '../build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab',
     )
   end
end
```

Then also it says somewhere, that  :

```
[11:16:18]: Couldn't find any new signed apk files...
```

yet I provided the path to the `aab`.

Anyone who can quickly unblock me please

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No actually I migrated to codemagic.com, am time bad

Comment: There is a new solution for this @PratapSharma

Answer (score 2):

```
desc "Deploy a new beta build to Google Play"
   lane :beta do
     build_number = number_of_commits()
     Dir.chdir "../.." do
       sh("flutter", "packages", "get")
       sh("flutter", "clean")
       sh("flutter", "build", "appbundle", "--build-number=#{build_number}")
     end
      upload_to_play_store(track: 'beta', aab: '../build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab')
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you try to publish a .aab file when an existing app was rejected by the play store.

There are 2 ways to work around the error:

1. Resolve the rejection and submit again
2. Upload .aab via web google play console for eg. in Alpha - Closed testing track, publish it and status should be set as "Changes in review"

[Reference link of this solution on Github](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/956#issuecomment-847691895)

Answer (score 0):

This Google API Error is due to Policy not set on the Play Store console and per @Rachit Rawat's answer above. Another thing you can do is to delete your already accepted apk/aab file and submit again.

check out my lesson learned: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234820023#comment31

Answer (score -1):

You are creating an apk with `task: "assemble"`, just change it for `task: "bundle"`.

Comment: Changed it but still same error, is there anything I have missed ?

Comment: Actually I don't know if this code implies to the `aab` or `apk` only ?

Comment: For the error it seems like it is searching for the apk, even you ask for the aab, but I notice there's a comma at the end of the line and there are more parameters after. Could you try to remove it?

Comment: I have removed it, but still the same issue, I don't if you can accept and we have like a short call on google meet

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @humblePilgrim, no I didn't